# How to add line before chapter change in below? Please see last given output which i need to do

Tags: ruby

> Below is the my code which giving output with inserting "000" and "00". Given content is tab separated "Genesis GEN 1 1"

```
file_name = ARGV[0] // here you can pass file with given contents.
start = "GEN"
output_name = "#{File.basename(file_name, '.*')}.tab"
output = File.open(output_name, 'w:utf-8')
File.open(file_name, "r:utf-8") do |li|
 li.each_with_index do |line,i|
   output << line.chomp.split("\t")[0...-1].join("\t") +"\t"+ "000\n" if i == 0
   output << line.chomp.split("\t")[0...-1].join("\t") +"\t"+ "00\n" if i == 0
   if (line.include? start.to_s)
     output << line
   else
     output << line.chomp.split("\t")[0...-1].join("\t") +"\t"+ "000\n"
     output << line.chomp.split("\t")[0...-1].join("\t") +"\t"+ "00\n"
     output << line
     start = line.split(" ")[1].to_s
   end
 end
end
```

> below is original text

1. Genesis GEN 1 1
2. Genesis GEN 1 2
3. Genesis GEN 1 3
4. Genesis GEN 2 1
5. Genesis GEN 2 2
6. Genesis GEN 2 3
7. Exodus  EXO 1 1
8. Exodus  EXO 1 2
9. Exodus  EXO 1 3
10. Exodus  EXO 2 1
11. Exodus  EXO 2 2
12. Exodus  EXO 2 3
13. Leviticus LEV 1 1
14. Leviticus LEV 1 2
15. Leviticus LEV 1 3
16. Leviticus LEV 2 1
17. Leviticus LEV 2 2
18. Leviticus LEV 2 3

> Below is output of my code

1. Genesis GEN 1   000
2. Genesis GEN 1   00
3. Genesis GEN 1 1
4. Genesis GEN 1 2
5. Genesis GEN 1 3
6. Genesis GEN 2 1
7. Genesis GEN 2 2
8. Genesis GEN 2 3
9. Exodus  EXO 1 000
10. Exodus  EXO 1 00
11. Exodus  EXO 1 1
12. Exodus  EXO 1 2
13. Exodus  EXO 1 3
14. Exodus  EXO 2 1
15. Exodus  EXO 2 2
16. Exodus  EXO 2 3
17. Leviticus LEV 1 000
18. Leviticus LEV 1 00
19. Leviticus LEV 1 1
20. Leviticus LEV 1 2
21. Leviticus LEV 1 3
22. Leviticus LEV 2 1
23. Leviticus LEV 2 2
24. Leviticus LEV 2 3

> I want to output as below. When third word number change then add first line as below.

1. Genesis GEN 1   000
2. Genesis GEN 1   00
3. Genesis GEN 1 1
4. Genesis GEN 1 2
5. Genesis GEN 1 3
6. Genesis GEN 2 00
7. Genesis GEN 2 1
8. Genesis GEN 2 2
9. Genesis GEN 2 3
10. Exodus  EXO 1 000
11. Exodus  EXO 1 00
12. Exodus  EXO 1 1
13. Exodus  EXO 1 2
14. Exodus  EXO 1 3
15. Exodus  EXO 2 00
16. Exodus  EXO 2 1
17. Exodus  EXO 2 2
18. Exodus  EXO 2 3
19. Leviticus LEV 1 000
20. Leviticus LEV 1 00
21. Leviticus LEV 1 1
22. Leviticus LEV 1 2
23. Leviticus LEV 1 3
24. Leviticus LEV 2 00
25. Leviticus LEV 2 1
26. Leviticus LEV 2 2
27. Leviticus LEV 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, the key thing being keep track of the current and previous chapters. There's probably a better, more ruby like way...

```
file_name = ARGV[0] // here you can pass file with given contents.

output_name = "#{File.basename(file_name, '.*')}.tab"
output = File.open(output_name, 'w:utf-8')

def split_line(line)
  line.chomp.split("\t")[0...-1].join("\t")
end

def book_from_line(line)
  line.split(" ")[1].to_s
end

def chapter_from_line(line)
  line.split(" ")[2].to_s
end

is_new_book = true
is_new_chapter = true

start = "GEN"
chapter = nil

File.open(file_name, "r:utf-8") do |li|
  li.each_with_index do |line, i|
    line_book = book_from_line(line)
    unless line_book == start
      start = line_book
      is_new_book = true
      is_new_chapter = true
    end

    line_chapter = chapter_from_line(line)
    unless line_chapter == chapter
      chapter = line_chapter
      is_new_chapter = true
    end

    output << split_line(line) +"\t"+ "000\n" if is_new_book
    output << split_line(line) +"\t"+ "00\n" if is_new_chapter
    output << line

    is_new_book = false
    is_new_chapter = false
  end
end
```